# prove that if $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$ then there are open balls such that $V=\bigcup_{j\in\Bbb N} B_j$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Prove that if $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^n$ then there are open balls such that $V=\bigcup_{j\in\Bbb N}B_j$.

I have the solution, but it is too short and it is not enough to prove it, also it's too complicated. Can someone prove this in order for me to learn it properly. Thank you :).

Comment: You should present any progress you've made so far (or a full solution if you have one). Doing that significantly increases the probability your question will be answered.

Comment: What is Lindelöf's theorem exactly?

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Let $D=\Bbb Q^n$, and let $\mathscr{B}=\{B(x,r):x\in D\text{ and }0<r\in\Bbb Q\}$; this is the set of open balls of rational radius in $\Bbb R^n$ whose centres have rational coordinates.

1. Explain why $\mathscr{B}$ is countable.
2. Show that for any open set $V\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ and any $x\in V$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq V$. Conclude that $V=\bigcup_{x\in V}B_x$, where $\{B_x:x\in V\}$ is a countable family of open balls. **Note:** It’s quite possible to have $B_x=B_y$ for distinct points $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Sorry:( I could not do:( please show me more explicit and teachable.

Comment: @B11b: I can’t say much more without simply doing the problem completely. You know that $\Bbb Q$ is countable, right? So $\Bbb Q^n$ is countable. The balls in $\mathscr{B}$ therefore have only countably many different centres, and each centre has balls of only countably many different radii, so $\mathscr{B}$ is countable union of countable sets and is therefore countable. For (2), if $x\in V$ you know that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq V$. $\Bbb Q^n$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$, so there is a point $p\in\Bbb Q^n$ such that $\|x-p\|<\frac{\epsilon}2$. Show that ...

Comment: ... if $0<r\le\frac{\epsilon}2$, then $x\in B(p,r)\subseteq B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq V$, and conclude that we can take $B_x=B(p,r)$ for any positive rational $r<\frac{\epsilon}2$.